# Java Create Strings Dynamically With Loops

Tags: java, string, loops

I need to create a program that creates strings dynamically with some sort of loop (for/while). It would start out as a single-character string with an ASCII value of 1, than 2, than 3, and so on, until is reached 128. Once it reached 128, it would be a two-character string, with the first character of an ASCII value of 1, and the second character being 1. It would then be 1;1, 1;2, 1;3, until the second digit reached 128, and then which the first character would have a value of 2. How is this logically possible?

Here's what I tried so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
        str = ((char) i) + "";
        for (int j = 0; j < 128; j++) {
            str += ((char) j) + "";
            //workWithString(str);
            System.out.println(str);
            str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
        }
    }
```

And this works, but only for 2 digits. I would like for it to work with up to 32 digits. Is there any easier way to accomplish this without having 32 for loops?

Thanks!

Comment: SO is not a code writing site. You should at least have a try and ask for help if you find that you don't manage to do that.

Comment: I did this homework assignment about 20 years ago. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: You might want to think about how the division (and modulus) operators work on numbers.

Comment: Here's a hint. Character.toString ((char) i); to get the character with an ASCII value of i. Make your loop and increment i to cycle thru all the ASCII characters.

Comment: @Ceelos Edited to show what I've tried.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, guys. Figured it out on my own. For anyone who's interested in the answer, I achieved it like so:

```
public static void addCharacter(String str, int depth) {
    for (int j = 33; j < 127; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
            str += ((char) j) + "";
            System.out.println(str);
            addCharacter(str, depth - 1);
            str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Where `depth` is the amount of digits you want it to calculate, and `str` is the string you want to add a character to.

Answer (score -2):

```
public class  StringCreator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i=0;i<=128;i++){
            for(j=0;j<10;j++){

                System.out.println(i+"."+j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not helping anyone by providing answers like this. Especially when they're wrong.